# Cocoapods ':head' equivalent for Mercurial

Tags: ios, mercurial, cocoapods

I've create private Cocoapods lib named `Common`, stored in a Mercurial repository.

Inside the `Podfile` I'm using:

`pod 'Common', :hg => "http://bitbucket.com/username/Common"`

When I run `pod install` it pulls the Pod, however, I don't get the latest commit in the repository.

I can use something like:

`pod 'Common', :hg => "http://bitbucket.com/username/Common",  :revision=>'fa7fd53266a0'`

But that means I always need to change the revision number to the latest commit.

Is there a way to tells the Podfile to take the latest commit in the repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution - just used `:revision=>'tip'`:

`pod 'Common', :hg => "http://bitbucket.com/username/Common", :revision=>'tip'`.

Update: Following @Ry4an's tip, I ended up using:

`pod 'Common', :hg => "http://bitbucket.com/username/Common", :branch =>'default'`.

Comment: Be careful with `tip` it's not the most recent commit in the `default` branch (like git's `master`) -- it's the most recent commit in *any* branch.  If you've got a branchy/PR-y workflow where things not yet merged into `default` aren't ready for prime-time you want to make sure to use `default` instead of `tip`.  And, if you're not using branches then `default` and `tip` will always be the same thing, so ... pretty much always use `default` when you'd use `tip`.